# MySQL returns incorrect data with use of join

Tags: mysql

I have join with a multiple tables. You can find the tables and MySQL query in this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/324ed/1).

These are the tables:

1. **users**

   ```
   id name
   1  abc
   2  xyz
   3  pqr
   ```
2. **friend**

   ```
   user_id friend_id
   1       2
   1       3
   2       3
   ```
3. **collection**

   ```
   id user_id friend_id amount
   1  1        2         100
   2  2        1        -100
   3  2        3         200
   4  3        2        -200
   5  1        3         300 
   6  3        1        -300
   ```
4. **bill**

   ```
   id use_id(bill_creator)
   1   1
   2   2
   3   2
   ```
5. **bill_person**

   ```
   id  bill_id user_id
   1  1        1
   2  1        2
   3  1        3
   4  2        2
   5  2        3
   6  3        2
   6  3        1
   ```

So far I have made this query:

```sql
SELECT mf.id
     , mf.name
     , c.amount AS amount,count(bp.user_id) AS no_common_bills
  FROM (
         SELECT fr.user_id AS user_id
              , fr.friend_id AS friend_id
           FROM friend fr
           JOIN users fru
             ON fru.id = fr.user_id
          WHERE fru.id IN (1)
          UNION
         SELECT fl.friend_id AS user_id
              , fl.user_id AS friend_id
           FROM friend fl
           JOIN users flf
             ON flf.id = fl.friend_id
          WHERE flf.id IN (1)
       ) f
  JOIN users mf
    ON mf.id = f.friend_id
  LEFT
  JOIN collection c
    ON c.friend_id = mf.id
   AND c.user_id = f.user_id
  LEFT JOIN bill_person bp 
    ON bp.user_id=f.user_id AND c.friend_id = mf.id
 GROUP BY mf.id
 ORDER BY mf.id
```

and my **output** of this query is

```
id   NAME AMOUNT NO_COMMON_BILLS
2    XYZ   100    2
3    PQR   300    2
```

but I want this result:

```
id   NAME AMOUNT NO_COMMON_BILLS
2    XYZ   100    2
3    PQR   300    1
```

I am getting wrong output at **NO_COMMON_BILLS**. Other than that, all values are correct.

Comment: Please add schema and data here instead of just SQLFiddle link.

Comment: @hims056 : i have too many table so i have made SQLFiddle to make it easier.

Comment: But what if the sqlfiddle site is down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third time's a charm...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/338dd/12

```
 SELECT u.name friend
      , COUNT(bp2.user_id) no_common_bills
   FROM users u
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT user_id me, friend_id them FROM friend WHERE user_id = 1 
         UNION 
        SELECT friend_id,user_id FROM friend WHERE friend_id = 1
      ) x
     ON x.them = u.id
   LEFT
   JOIN bill_person bp1
    ON bp1.user_id = x.them
   LEFT
   JOIN bill_person bp2
     ON bp2.bill_id = bp1.bill_id
    AND bp2.user_id = x.me
  WHERE u.id <> 1
  GROUP 
     BY friend;

 FRIEND     NO_COMMON_BILLS
 jkl        0
 mno        0
 pqr        1
 xyz        2
```

Comment: see i am `counting number of bills common between user and his each friends`.so i need `count of bill_id` between his each friend

Comment: hey your query works but when `if user has a entry in friend table` but he has `no bills` with him at that time i need `answer null or 0` see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/338dd/1 i have change the data and you can see that  i can not get the `mno(user_id=4) and jkl(user_id=5)`

Comment: I try `left join` and `count(f.user_id)` but it's not working.

Comment: no, you are getting wrong my friend. i don't want `abc` in the result but i want his remaining friend which has `no_common_bills is 0`.Please see this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/338dd/2)

Comment: i can exclude abc from result but i am not getting that two rows `mno(user_id=4) and jkl(user_id=5)` in my query result that's a problem.